# Prevent User from Inputing Invalid Operators

Tags: python, operator-keyword

If these 4 letters `E`/`A`/`S`/`T` are my operators below, how can I make it so the user can not enter an invalid operator. Basically anything other than listed below?

```
print("Available Operators:")
print("'E' sets starting number")
print("'A' for addition")
print("'S' for subtraction")
print("'T' will terminate program")

# Prompt user to select the operator 
choice = input("Select Operator (e/a/s/t): ")
```

Comment: valid_entries = "e", "a", "s", "t"

    while true:
    choice = input()
    if choice in valid_entry:
        break
    print("Please enter a valid letter.")

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` to test against a list of options:

```
direction = input()
if direction in 'NESW':
    # valid input
else:
    # invalid input
```

Comment: I am not necessarily trying to find a direction, just "bind" certain keys in a sense to either loop, add, subtract, or exit

Comment: Ehh, then you can just change the variable names and the option list. I was just providing an example.

Comment: If they enter "Z" lets say, I need it to catch the error and loop back till they enter a valid "E" "A" "S" or "T"

Answer (score 0):

```
valid_entries = {'E', 'A', 'S', 'T'}

while True:
    result = input()
    if result in valid_entries:
        break
    print('Please enter a valid letter')
```